# Inclusão de arquivos em projetos do Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net

Boa noite. Gostaria de saber se é possível incluir um arquivo em um projeto do Visual Studio através de programação em tempo de execução ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente fazer dessa forma:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"C:\MyFolder\MyProject.csproj");
string strNewItem = @"C:\MyImages\IMG_20180926-WA0017.jpg";

if (p.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EvaluatedInclude == strNewItem) == null) 
{ 
    p.AddItem("_img", strNewItem);
    p.Save(); 
}
```

Obtém o projeto e depois valida se o ficheiro que pretende incluir ainda não existe, onde nesse caso adiciona-o à pasta `_img` e grava o projeto.

Indicação dada pelo utilizador [Ray Carneiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/127010/ray-carneiro).


Necessário referenciar `Microsoft.Build.dll`.

Comment: Obrigado João martins

Comment: Resposta editada para conter a livraria necessária para o código executar.

Comment: A resposta ajudou-o? Conseguiu resolver o problema?